# Using custom httpmodule and have 'Sys' is undefined errors

Tags: httpmodule, scriptresource.axd

I have created my own custom httpmodule to handle url rewriting so that urls like `www.contoso.com/help/default.aspx` will point to `www.contoso.com/default.aspx` where the actual resource is located.

This works fine, but because of my implementation of an httpmodule I am having problems with ScriptResource.axd not being run properly to add the javascript needed to perform button clicks or functionality afforded by ajax.

I have IIS7 set to use the classic pipeline app pool.  I have also ensured that the web.config file has the necessary information in it.

I have pasted this information below. Can someone identify something that I have missed or should have configured differently?

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
                <remove  path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" />
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="myHandler" />
      <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="myModule" type="myModule" />
        </httpModules>
```

Comment: <httpModules> <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> <add name="myModule" type="myModule" /> </httpModules>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your custom httpmodule:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
    }

    private void Application_OnAfterProcess(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        if (context.Request.Headers["x-microsoftajax"] == null)
        {
            if ((!System.IO.File.Exists(application.Request.PhysicalPath)) &&
                (!application.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".axd")) &&
                (!application.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".asmx")))
                {
                    string newUrl = "~/Search.aspx?q=" 
                        + context.Server.UrlEncode(application.Request.Url.Segments.Last());
                        ...
                    context.RewritePath(newUrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {    
         context.PostResolveRequestCache += (new EventHandler(this.Application_OnAfterProcess));
    }
}
```